# How to configure permissions for Samba and SFTP in a compatible way?

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, sftp

I have a NAS made by myself with Linux Debian and this path shared via Samba:

```
drwxrwxrwx 5 nobody nogroup  4096 Jan 22 12:57 shared
```

My goal is to have this layout:

```
└── shared
    ├── private
    └── public
        └── upload
        └── ...other stuff...
```

where I want these conditions:

- I want 'shared' and all subdirectories to be a Samba resource shared on local lan with anonymous access and no restrictions (no device should be able to access using Samba from outside the local LAN)
- I want 'public' to be a sftp chroot jail for all users belonging to my '**sftpusers**' group, all with no /home directory themselves, but starting at /public. I want this directory and its subdirectories to be only readable for users via sftp, but maintaining the Samba free access described previously
- I want 'upload' to be the only exception inside 'public' where sftp users can write and upload things, and occasionally delete the files they own (because they uploaded them). I also want free access via Samba in this 'upload' directory

Currently, I have these directories created:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4096 Jan 14 12:35 private
drwxr-xr-x 3 nobody nogroup 4096 Jan 16 16:44 public
```

As you see I made all the 'shared' subdirectories property of user 'nobody' and group 'nogroup' because I know it is the default for Samba, but this is not a requirement of mine.

My Samba config is:

```
[global]
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        server role = standalone server
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        workgroup = ARCADIA
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        hosts allow = 192.168.0.


[shared]
        create mask = 0777
        directory mask = 0777
        guest ok = Yes
        path = /mnt/nas/shared
        read only = No


[printers]
        browseable = No
        comment = All Printers
        create mask = 0700
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes
```

Right now, I'm mounting the Samba resource with this line from my laptop:

```
//192.168.0.249/shared                             /mnt/corelli             cifs   rw,guest,uid=1000,gid=1000,noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,user 0 0
```

I didn't start yet with the SFTP server, but I'm having difficulties with permissions with Samba because it doesn't allow to write in 'public' and 'private'. Also I don't know which permissions and default owner groups should I apply to files/directories for both the sftp users to be restricted under 'public' and the Samba users to have unrestricted access under 'shared' from the local lan.

Comment: First bullet point. You can't share it "exclusively" if you want part of the directory tree shared elsewhere. That's not what "exclusive" means

Comment: Yes, I'm editing, but I meant that a device through Samba should only be able to access within my local LAN